# How to Hide or Show Custom attribute based on other custom attribute in Product detail/edit page from Adminpanel Magento 2.4?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I have created the Product's custom attributes programmatically(**Setup->Installdata.php**).

```
 $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'serial_code_use_customer',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Issue By Customer Group',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable',
                'group' => self::GROUP_LABEL,
                'sort_order' => 3,
                'note' => 'Enable automatic issuing of codes based on customer group.'
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'serial_code_customer_groups',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Select Customer Groups',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Source\Group::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable',
                'group' => self::GROUP_LABEL,
                'sort_order' => 4,
                'note' => 'Customers in selected groups will be issued codes automatically when product is ordered.'
            ]
        );
```

I want to Hide or Show a Custom attribute based on other custom attributes in the Product detail/edit page from Adminpanel Magento 2.4.x?

For example, there is a toggle **on click (yes/no) the Customer Groups will be Hide / Show**.

[image]

Comment: please check the following answer, it may help you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344609/81049

Answer (score 0):

To hide custom product attributes from the admin product detail page you need to create UpgradeData.php in the My/Catalog/Setup directory.
Code:

> $eavSetup->updateAttribute(Product::ENTITY, $attrCode, 'is_visible',
> '0');

Comment: Sorry but that was not expected. The question is about dependency. As per your solution that will set the default value as visible/hidden.